# Сравнение двух путей и получение общей части с конца

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Создаю код бекапа заменяемых файлов. Имеется:

```
array<String^>^ FilesToCopy = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(pc->OBMFolder(), modName), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
/* Создаем бекап */
    if (makeBackUp){
        array<String^>^ FilesInGame = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(getGP->ModsFolder(), "SP2", "data"), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
        for (int i = 0; i < FilesToCopy->Length; i++){
            String^ FileToCopy = Path::GetFileName(FilesToCopy[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < FilesInGame->Length; j++){
                String^ FileInGame = Path::GetFileName(FilesInGame[j]);
                if (FileToCopy == FileInGame){
                    String^ NewPackFolder = Path::Combine(pc->OBMFolder(), wnd->GetInputText());
                    if (!Directory::Exists(NewPackFolder)) Directory::CreateDirectory(NewPackFolder);

                    ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА, Нужно получить максимально возможную общуй часть для двух входных путей, и скопировать файл в новую папку сохраняя иерархию каталогов.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

А проблема в следующем:
Нужно сравнить два полных имени файла и вернуть их максимально общую часть с конца строк.

Например:

```
Путь А: С:\Folder\docs\file.txt
Путь Б: E:\Directory\Folder1\docs\file.txt
```

Нужно получить на выходе

```
docs\file.txt
```

Пока не очень понимаю как правильно реализовать данную функцию. Нужен алгоритм с примером. Не важно C# или C++CLI, я адаптирую под себя сам, просто на C# больше народу.

Comment: Мало входных примеров. Что должна выводить функция для `c:\asdf.doc` и для `D:\123.txt`? Нужно вывести :\ или нужно отбрасывать имена дисков и тогда ответ будет `.`? Непонятно, вам нужен алгоритм или вам нужен конкретный пример кода (у вас два разных языка в тегах)? У меня есть подозрение, что вы не осознали и не верблизовали  важное условие, что имя файла всегда одинаково (т.е. нельзя запускать подобную проверку для file.txt и для file1.txt)

Comment: Эта функция будет внутри if по логическому условию если имена конечных файлов двух путей равны, то есть по предложеному вами примеру дело до этой функции не дойдет. Я делаю код для создания бекапа заменяемых файлов.

Comment: Жмите кнопку править и редактируйте пост. Всё важное в условиях задачи должно быть не в комментариях, а в самом вопросе. А вообще, если всё так - то что вам мешает найти максимальную подстроку с конца, если у вас гарантированно на конце уже есть общая строка в виде имени файла?

Comment: Алгоритм простой. Возьмём например первый путь за основу (можно второй, там тоже есть на конце подстрока `file.txt`) и найдём в ней позицию подстроки `file.txt`) и во втором пути тоже. В цикле начнём а) уменьшать позицию в первом пути на единицу и смотреть, совпали ли с увеличенной на 1 подстрокой во втором пути до того момента, пока некуда будет уменьшать (полное совпадение), либо пока строки не разойдутся. Профит!?

Comment: @AK , есть ли стандартные методы "уменьшения позиции"? Типа Path::GetFileName() или предется мудрить с стринг сплитом?

Comment: Да, цикл for называется. Есть в обоих языках.

Comment: Показал пример в коде на c# постаравшись использовать только те конструкции, которые есть в обоих языках. Просто в качестве образца псевдокода, раз вам алгоритм непонятен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как же, вопрос с меткой C# и никто не предложил Linq-вариант?

Исправляем:

```
var s1 = @"С:\Folder\docs\file.txt";
var s2 = @"E:\Directory\Folder1\docs\file.txt";
var s3 = new string(
    s1.Reverse()
      .Zip(s2.Reverse(), (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 ? c1 : -1)
      .TakeWhile(x => x > -1)
      .Reverse()
      .Select(x => (char)x)
      .ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(s3);
```

Выведет `\docs\file.txt`

Если вместо `-1` использовать `(char)0` и в `TakeWhile` поправить условие, то можно выкинуть `Select`

В C++/CLI переведете сами.

Почти то же самое, но сравниваем по секциям (специфично именно для путей), более правильное решение:

```
var s1 = @"C:\Folder\docs\file.txt";
var s2 = @"E:\Directory\Folder1\docs\file.txt";
var s3 = string.Join("\\",
            EnumerateParts(s1)
                .Zip(EnumerateParts(s2), (p1, p2) => p1 == p2 ? p1 : null)
                .TakeWhile(p => p != null)
                .Reverse());
Console.WriteLine(s3);
```

Где `EnumerateParts`:

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateParts(string path)
{
    var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
    while (path != root)
    {
        yield return Path.GetFileName(path);
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    }
    yield return root;
}
```

Comment: Второе решение (с EnumerateParts) правильное. Первое не сработает на `C:\good\file.txt` и `C:\hood\file.txt`, оно выдаст `ood\file.txt`, которое не является каталогом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам указание на то, как можно сделать:

```
void Main()
{
    var common = this.GetCommonPathFromEnd(@"А: С:\Folder\docs\file.txt", @"E:\Directory\Folder1\docs\file.txt");
    common.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public string GetCommonPathFromEnd(string path1, string path2)
{
    //path1.Length.Dump();
    //path2.Length.Dump();
    var commonSymbols = 0;
    for(var i = commonSymbols; i < path1.Length || i < path2.Length ; i++)
    {
        //path1.Substring(path1.Length - i).Dump();
        //path2.Substring(path2.Length - i).Dump();
        if(!string.Equals(path1.Substring(path1.Length - i), path2.Substring(path2.Length - i)))
            break;

        commonSymbols = i;

        //"".Dump();
    }

    //commonSymbols.Dump();

    return path1.Substring(path1.Length - commonSymbols);
}
```

Вывод:

```
t
t

xt
xt

txt
txt

.txt
.txt

e.txt
e.txt

le.txt
le.txt

ile.txt
ile.txt

file.txt
file.txt

\file.txt
\file.txt

s\file.txt
s\file.txt

cs\file.txt
cs\file.txt

ocs\file.txt
ocs\file.txt

docs\file.txt
docs\file.txt

\docs\file.txt
\docs\file.txt

r\docs\file.txt
1\docs\file.txt
```

Закомментирован вспомогательный вывод.