# Сортировка списка папок по вложенности

Tags: c#, wpf, сортировка

Есть список директорий (просто строки), которые необходимо отсортировать. Например:
*C:\Program Files\Microsoft

C:\Program Files (x86)

C:\Program Files*

Стандартная сортировка:
*C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files (x86)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft*

Надо чтобы список сортировался в порядке вложенности папок:
*C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files\Microsoft

C:\Program Files (x86)*

В действительности пути хранятся в `ObservableCollection<AnalyseObject> Pathes` где *AnalyseObject* класс:

```
public class AnalyseObject
{
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; } //enum: диск / папка / файл
    public string Path { get;  set; } //содержит выше приведенные значения
    public bool IsAnalyzed { get ; set; } //true - анализировать, false - нет
}
```

Коллекция привязана к таблице на форме (WPF) с помощью:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="pathesVS" Source="{Binding Pathes}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Path" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Каким образом можно добиться такой сортировки?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, чтобы после `a` выводилось всё что лежит в `a`?

Comment: Если вы будете хранить папки в древовидной структуре, то достаточно будет добавить в нее что-то вроде `IEnumerable<Entry> Enumerate() { yield return this; foreach (var child in Children) foreach (var item in child.Enumerate()) yield return item; }`

Comment: или, чуть короче: `IEnumerable<Entry> Enumerate() => Children.SelectMany(child => child.Enumerate()).Prepend(this);`

Comment: Папки получаются либо из json'а, либо из текстового файла, в которых хранятся просто списком в том виде котором указал. Их может быть с несколько десятков тысяч. Полагаю проще и быстрее их будет отсортировать, чем собирать дерево. Только не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не подскажите каким способом можно преобразовать имеющийся список в древовидную структуру?

Comment: Мне кажется, что если не строить дерево, то отсортировать так как вы хотите не получится. Хотя, конечно, можно написать специальный компарер, делающий это. Но я буду за ПК только завтра, если никто раньше не напишет ответ, то попробую вам помочь

Answer (score 2):

Пошел по другому пути. Дополнил класс *AnalyseObject*:

```
public class AnalyseObject : IComparable<AnalyseObject>
{
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; } //enum: диск / папка / файл
    public string Path { get;  set; } //содержит выше приведенные значения
    public bool IsAnalyzed { get ; set; } //true - анализировать, false - нет

    public int CompareTo(AnalyseObject other)
    {
        if (this.Path == other.Path)
            return 0;

        int thisPathLength = this.Path.Length;
        int otherPathLength = other.Path.Length;
        int maxIndex = Math.Min(thisPathLength - 1, otherPathLength - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++)
        {
            if (this.Path[i] == other.Path[i]) continue;
            if (this.Path[i] == '\\') return -1;
            if (other.Path[i] == '\\') return 1;
            return this.Path[i] < other.Path[i] ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return thisPathLength < otherPathLength ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Добавил:

```
public static class ObservableCollection
{
    public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, bool byDescending = false)
    {
        if (!byDescending)
        {
            List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
            source.Clear();
            foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
            {
                source.Add(sortedItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
            source.Clear();
            foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
            {
                source.Add(sortedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сортировку провожу принудительно:

```
Pathes.Sort(p => p);
```

Наверно далеко не самый оптимальный вариант, но вроде работает как надо. Буду признателен если кто-то предложит вариант лучше.

Comment: О, да, примерно что я вам и предлагал. Сейчас пишу свой ответ.

Comment: Нюанс — с путями лучше работать специально созданными для этого средствами: классы `Path`, `Directory`, `File` и т. п.

Answer (score 2):

В первом приближении я бы сделал как-то так:

Возьмем [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786818/218063) метод `EnumerateParts` и напишем на его основе компарер:

```
class PathComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xParts = EnumerateParts(x).Reverse().ToList();
        var yParts = EnumerateParts(y).Reverse().ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < xParts.Count && i < yParts.Count; ++i)
        {
            var c = string.Compare(xParts[i], yParts[i]);
            if (c != 0) return c;
        }
        return xParts.Count.CompareTo(yParts.Count);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateParts(string path)
    {
        var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
        while (path != root)
        {
            yield return Path.GetFileName(path);
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
        yield return root;
    }
}
```

Теперь можно пользоваться так:

```
var source = new[]
{
    @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft",
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)",
    @"C:\Program Files"
};
foreach (var p in source.OrderBy(s => s, new PathComparer()))
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Работает как надо, но если поставить брейкпоинт в `EnumerateParts`, то можно подсчитать, что для 3х строк он вызывается аж 10 раз, что может быть очень неэффективно, поэтому я бы переписал код так, чтобы `EnumerateParts` вызывался только один раз для каждой строки. Например:

```
class PathParts : IComparable<PathParts>
{
    readonly List<string> parts;

    public PathParts(string path)
    {
        parts = EnumerateParts(path).Reverse().ToList();
    }

    public int CompareTo(PathParts other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count && i < other.parts.Count; ++i)
        {
            var c = string.Compare(parts[i], other.parts[i]);
            if (c != 0) return c;
        }
        return parts.Count.CompareTo(other.parts.Count);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateParts(string path)
    {
        var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
        while (path != root)
        {
            yield return Path.GetFileName(path);
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
        yield return root;
    }
}
```

и теперь:

```
var source = new[]
{
    @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft",
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)",
    @"C:\Program Files"
};
var ordered = source.Select(s => new { s, pp = new PathParts(s) })
                    .OrderBy(a => a.pp)
                    .Select(a => a.s);
foreach (var p in ordered)
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Ну и теперь можете сделать `PathParts` вложенным приватным классом в своем `AnalyseObject`, также создавать экземпляр `PathParts` один раз при создании и потом выставить метод:

```
public int CompareTo(AnalyseObject other) => pathParts.CompareTo(other.pathParts);
```

Comment: Тоже интересный вариант. Я пока остановлюсь на своем, но может и ваш где использую. Правда заметил одну недоработку - если в массив путей добавить такие же, но на диске D, то пути перемешаются - по папкам сортировка будет верная, но диски вперемешку. Как-то так: 1."D:\Program Files", 2."C:\Program Files", 3."C:\Program Files\Microsoft", 4."D:\Program Files\Microsoft", 5."C:\Program Files (x86)", 6."D:\Program Files (x86)".

Comment: Ага, дельное замечание, часть с названием диска не попадает в коллекцию `parts`, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Исправил, теперь название диска тоже попадает в массив кусков пути

Answer (score 1):

Я буду считать, что вы знаете как получить список директорий (см. [вопросы типа такого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7296956/5752652)), поэтому сосредоточусь только на построении linq-запроса, который отсортирует вашу коллекцию.

Мои тестовые данные будут такие:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoriesStub()
{
    return new string[]
    {
         @"C:\Documents and Settings"
        ,@"C:\Program Files"
        ,@"C:\Program Files (x86)"
        ,@"C:\Users"
        ,@"C:\Windows"
        ,@"C:\git\gitlab.com"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\Common Files"
        ,@"C:\git\github.com"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\dotnet"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\Git"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\Git\bin"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\Git\dev\shm"
        ,@"C:\git"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\nodejs"
        ,@"C:\Program Files\Git\dev\mqueue"
    };
}
```

В первую очередь я посчитаю в каждой строке количество символов `\`. Чем больше будет таких символов, тем глубже будет лежать папка, тем больше её level:

```
var paths = this.GetDirectoriesStub();

paths.Select(x => new { Path = x, Level = x.Count(y => y == '\\')} )
     .Dump();
```

Получаем следующий набор данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь сортируем нужным нам образом. Судя по озвученнм условиям, надо во-первых отсортировать по уровню вложенности, а во-вторых — по имени папки:

```
paths.Select(x => new { Path = x, Level = x.Count(y => y == '\\') })
     .OrderBy(x => x.Level)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Path)
     .Dump();
```

Получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то некрасиво. Попробуем поменять сортировку: сначала по x.Path, потом по x.Level:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, так гораздо логичнее и понятнее.

---

Update

> Очень близко, но не совсем то. Обратите внимание на "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)", который расположен между "C:\Program Files" и "C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files". А по логике он должен выводиться после всех
>   вложенных в "C:\Program Files"

Вот тут уже возможно пора строить дерево, чтобы было видно, у какой папки какие дочерние. Но в принципе, можно извернуться и по-прежнему обойтись сортировкой.

Добавим немного магии с весовыми коэффициентами:

```
paths.Select(x => new { 
        Path = x, 
        PathForSorting = (x + '\x01').Replace('\\', '\x02'), 
        Level = x.Count(y => y == '\\') })
     .OrderBy(x => x.PathForSorting)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Path)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
     .Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе, работает и если убрать `.Replace('\\', '\x02')` - но для надёжности оставил полный вариант. (В полном варианте можно будет ещё некоторые дополнительные условия учесть, если понадобится)

```
paths.Select(x => new { 
        Path = x, 
        PathForSorting = (x + '\x01'),//.Replace('\\', '\x02'), 
        Level = x.Count(y => y == '\\') })
     .OrderBy(x => x.PathForSorting)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Path)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
     .Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пояснение магии. Зачем был введён первый символ? Чтобы гарантированно различать кто является родителем, а кто потомком. Если ранее достаточно было считать, что "у кого длина строки меньше - тот и выше в сортировке / иерархии", то с учётом примера уже нужно определять точнее.

Второй символ я ввёл исключительно для наглядности, выбрав его больше, чем символ1. Неявно правило сортировки "\x01 показывать выше \x02" звучит как "родительская папка (это у нас символ \x01) располагать выше любых вложенных в неё папок (это символ 2)". Это правило избыточно и введено только для наглядности, чтобы можно было вербализировать это правило (явное лучше неявного).

В целом, я считаю, что уже в этом месте количество применённой магии подходит уже к отметке, где пора думать над построением дерева.

Причин тут две.

Во-первых, некоторая неочевидность алгоритма (магия).

Во-вторых, вполне возможно, что у вас в именах директорий встретятся символы ниже пробельного (всякие кривые папки) и в реальном приложении лучше избегать таких хаков. Оно вам надо, чтобы пользователи программы предпочли другое ПО, которое не будет глючить даже в случае некорректных папок на диске? )

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Очень близко, но не совсем то. Обратите внимание на "C:\Program Files (x86)", который расположен между "C:\Program Files"  и "C:\Program Files\Common Files". А по логике он должен выводиться после всех вложенных в "C:\Program Files".

Comment: @krok Это связано с тем, что символ `\` тоже является некоторым символом и сортируется каким-то образом. Вы можете предварительно его удалить, либо заменить на символ, который поставит его в начало списка (например, 'a' или пробел), либо на символ, который поставит его в конец списка (например, 'Z').

Comment: @krok Обновил ответ. В принципе, если не подойдут коэффициенты (посмотрите, может быть вы ещё какое-то условие забыли указать) - уже можно подумывать о построении дерева, т.к. при усложнении правил проще будет их явно видеть на дереве, чем разбираться в использованной магии.

Comment: Почему-то магия не работает, пробел оказывается приоритетней символов '\x01' '\x02'. Результат тот же. Не хочет "C:\Program Files (x86)" перемещаться ниже "C:\Program Files\Common Files" и прочих вложенных в "C:\Program Files".

Comment: @krok А, я понял что вы хотите. Нет, этого уже сортировкой не сделать - нужно честно дерево строить, я по крайней мере вариантов не вижу. Могу оставить пока ответ, вдруг кого-то натолкнёт на способ допилить, но как по мне - нужно удалить эту ветку как тупиковую.